# How can I obtain the string path of a drawing to use for CreateJs?

Tags: path, createjs

I have a code that uses Createjs, similar to this example:
https://codepen.io/durandpierrelouis/pen/xrKbXB

I'm interested to know how is the below string of the path generated: (how can we get this string?)
"AiwFdQhKhKAAhoIAAlVQAAhoBKhKQBKhKBmAAQBoAABJBKQBKBKAABoIAAFVQAABohKBKQhJBKhoAAQhmAAhKhKg"

```
this.shape_14.graphics.f("#E2D3E5").s().p("AiwFdQhKhKAAhoIAAlVQAAhoBKhKQBKhKBmAAQBoAABJBKQBKBKAABoIAAFVQAABohKBKQhJBKhoAAQhmAAhKhKg");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcut method to compress the path instructions generated by Adobe Animate. EaselJS decodes it using [graphicsInstance.decodePath()](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_decodePath).

There is some information on how it works in the docs, but it's not really intended for manual usage. In Animate you can also turn this feature off in your document, and get regular instructions.